# Add caption to pdf import

Tags: pdftex

I want to import a figure in pdf format and add a caption below the import.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \includepdf[width=\textwidth]{figures/figure1}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
```

Unfortunately, the caption appears at the top of the page, not below the included pdf. Why is that so and is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have to use \includepdf to import the figure?

Everything should work just fine if you use \includegraphics (which can include PDF figures just fine with pdftex in my experience).

Comment: So simple. Did the trick. Thank you